# UIImagePickerController is landscape while taking photo, but portrait during preview

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

.. and I don't like that because my entire app is Landscape-Only.

How can I get the UIImagePickerController to show the preview in Landscape orientation?

Here's an example of what I mean. When I begin taking the photo it looks like this:

[image]

But after I snap the photo and the UIImagePickerController shows me the preview with Use/Retake buttons, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I tell the UIImagePickerController to stay in landscape the entire time, showing the preview in a landscape position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you've read the documentation that says UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

...and that you're looking for an alternative/workaround?

Comment: So, yes, I did miss that notice in the documentation, but it seems to be contradictory since the camera UI is CLEARLY in landscape orientation when I'm taking the photo.

Comment: Agree completely, seems like the ran out of time on that one : )

Comment: But there is an app in the appstore named "GridLens" taking images in the Landscape mode also??